# xcopy & robocopy - Encrypted during transfer?

Tags: windows, encryption, robocopy, xcopy

I need to transfer some files on some windows hosts, as i come from the unix side, i searched for a tool similar to scp or rsync. I came across xcopy and robocopy and searched the manuals for a hint if the filestream is encrypted or not.

The only thing i found is the /EFSRAW switch of robocopy, which lets you transfer encrypted files.

Before i turn on my wireshark, let me ask the question to the Windows guys: Do this tools encrypt the transfer or not?

Comment: Are the servers in the same forest?

Comment: Yes. They are in the same forest

Comment: In the same forest, it's easy to have the servers use Kerberos based IPsec (it's literally a few mouseclicks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robocopy and xcopy do not encrypt their connections.  You can, of course, run them over a VPN connection or something like that.

Comment: That's correct, they massively pre-date the days where copying over internal networks was considered to require encryption and the Internet was a distant dream :)